# Intellij Debug Console font size

Tags: intellij-idea

Today after starting Intellij I noticed I have a giant font in the Debug Console. I have changed the console font setting  under Editor->Color Scheme->Console Font but this affects only "terminal" window, not the debug console. How to change the font size of the Debug console ? I use Intellij Ultimate 2019.2 on Mac.

[image]

Comment: File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Font is the correct setting. Please share the screenshot with the font configuration. Did you try to restart the IDE?

Comment: @bdskfsdk321dsad3
As far as I remember you can decrease font size in the terminal with Ctrl + mouse wheel. If it's not enable by default you can enable this option like:
File > Settings... > Editor > General : Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel. Hope that it will works as it supposes.

Comment: @bdskfsdk321dsad3 please accept my/martins answer as correct, so it gets more visibility. Took me lots of time to find it.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin had the right answer in his comment:

> As far as I remember you can decrease font size in the terminal with
> Ctrl + mouse wheel. If it's not enable by default you can enable this
> option like: File > Settings... > Editor > General : Change font size
> (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel. Hope that it will works as it supposes.

This works perfectly as of 2023.